# How to convert from saving to a text file to saving to an excel file in python using csv

Tags: python, excel, csv, random

I have been programming a maths quiz and  have been saving my answer to a text file however now I would like to save these to a excel file in and I have been told I would need to import cvs and use this. I have try to do this but then i have received copious amounts of error. Any answer would would much appreciated. I feel the code I have now is fairly easy to understand and is user friendly.

```
class_number = prompt_int_big("Before your score is saved ,are you in class 1, 2 or 3? Press the matching number")

filename = (str(class_number) + "csv")
with open(filename, 'a') as f:
    f.write("\n" + str(name) + " scored " + str(score) +  " on difficulty level " + str(level_of_difficulty) + "\n")
with open(filename) as f:
    lines = [line for line in f if line.strip()]
    lines.sort()

if prompt_bool("Do you wish to view previous results for your class"):
    for line in lines:
        print (line)
else:
    sys.exit("Thanks for taking part in the quiz, your teacher should discuss your score with you later")
```

Comment: "I feel the code I have now is fairly easy to understand and is user friendly" :D it took me like 7 seconds to scroll through it (and that was just vertical). Please provide a [minimal example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: `filename` does not provide a valid filename. You need `".csv"` extension. Also, there is a python module specifically for reading and writing csv files which will probably help you https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html